# ggplot2 version of shepard plot, i.e. vegan::stressplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

There seems to be quite a bit of information for plotting NMDS outputs (i.e. NMDS1 vs NMDS1) using `ggplot2` however I cannot find a way to plot the `vegan::stressplot()` (shepard's plot) using `ggplot2`.

Is there a way to produce a `ggplot2` version of a `metaMDS` output?

**Reproducible code**

```r
library(vegan)

set.seed(2)

community_matrix = matrix(
  sample(1:100,300,replace=T),nrow=10,
  dimnames=list(paste("community",1:10,sep=""),paste("sp",1:30,sep="")))

example_NMDS=metaMDS(community_matrix, k=2) 

stressplot(example_NMDS)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: what is your specific programming question? asking for software recommendations is off-topic

Comment: To produce a stressplot (shepard's plot) using ggplot2. I will rephrase the question now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround to plot a very similar plot using `ggplot2`.The trick was to get the structure of the `stressplot(example_NMDS)` and extract the data stored in that object. I used the `tidyverse` package that includes `ggplot` and other packages such as `tidyr` that contains the `pivot_longer` function.

```
library(vegan)
library(tidyverse)

# Analyze the structure of the stressplot
# Notice there's an x, y and yf list
str(stressplot(example_NMDS))

# Create a tibble that contains the data from stressplot
df <- tibble(x = stressplot(example_NMDS)$x,
       y = stressplot(example_NMDS)$y,
       yf = stressplot(example_NMDS)$yf) %>%
  # Change data to long format
  pivot_longer(cols = c(y, yf),
               names_to = "var")

# Create plot
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x,
             y = value)) +
  # Add points just for y values
  geom_point(data = df %>%
               filter(var == "y")) +
  # Add line just for yf values
  geom_step(data = df %>%
              filter(var == "yf"),
            col = "red",
            direction = "vh") +
  # Change axis labels
  labs(x = "Observed Dissimilarity", y = "Ordination Distance") +
  # Add bw theme
  theme_bw()
```

[image: stressplot]